# Downloading files off of a wiki site while keeping them organized

Tags: download, wget, wiki

I've been tasked with exporting all of the files from a companies wiki site. I understand that it's not too difficult to export them all, but I was wondering if there is an efficient way to export them while keeping them in a similar structure/organization so that I do not just have hundreds of files that aren't organized. It's a MoinMoin wiki and I do have access to the server the wiki is running on. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since you can't access the server, you can try to mirror the wiki recursively using `wget`:

```
wget --no-parent \
     --mirror \
     --page-requisites \
     --adjust-extension \
     <home page url>
```

The options I used are described in the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html) as follows:

> --no-parent
>
> ...very useful way of limiting directories is disallowing retrieval of the links that refer to the hierarchy above than the beginning directory
>
> --mirror
>
> ...This option turns on recursion and time-stamping, sets infinite recursion depth and keeps FTP directory listings.
>
> --page-requisites
>
> ...This option causes Wget to download all the files that are necessary to properly display a given HTML page
>
> --adjust-extension
>
> ...If a file of type ‘application/xhtml+xml’ or ‘text/html’ is downloaded and the URL does not end with the regexp ‘.[Hh][Tt][Mm][Ll]?’, this option will cause the suffix ‘.html’ to be appended to the local filename.

Answer (score 0):

Log into the server, and just copy your_path/wiki/data and its subfolders and contents. There shouldn't be any symbolic links to worry about so something like the following should work.

```
cp -R your_path/wiki/data your_destination
```

However, when you say "exporting all files", this might also mean some files not in wiki/data (configuration files, cgi executables and files in the public folders). Also, it is not clear if you only want just the current version of pages and their uploads, or you want the complete wiki with all its page histories and logs.